# Is it possible to focus on textarea after selecting option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, textarea

After adding text inside textarea i would like to focus caret just after this input. Unfortunately I can't make function focus() to be called. Although when I use focus() on click it works perfectly

Here is my function:

```js
function append_textarea(textarea, select, div_for_select) {
    $(textarea).on('keyup paste cut mouseup', function (event) {
        var contentHeight = $(this).textareaHelper('height');
        $(this).height(contentHeight);
        var obj = $(this).textareaHelper('caretPos');
        var left = obj.left + 15;
        var top = obj.top + 50;
        if (event.which === 219) {
            $(div_for_select).attr('style', 'top: ' + top + 'px;' + ' left: ' + left + 'px;').fadeIn();
            openDropdown(select);
        } else if (event.which === 221) {
            $(div_for_select).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
    $(div_for_select).on('keydown click', function (event) {
        if (event.which === 13 || event.which === 1) {
            var $txt = $(textarea);
            var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
            var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
            var txtToAdd = $(select).val();
            $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos)).focus();
            $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
    $(textarea).keyup();

    function openDropdown(elementId) {
        function down() {
            var pos = $(this).offset(); // remember position
            var len = $(this).find("option").length;
            if (len > 20) {
                len = 20;
            }
            $(this).css("position", "absolute");
            $(this).css("zIndex", 9999);
            $(this).offset(pos);   // reset position
            $(this).attr("size", len); // open dropdown
            $(this).unbind("focus", down);
            $(this).trigger('focus');
        }

        function up() {
            $(this).css("position", "static");
            $(this).attr("size", "1");  // close dropdown
            $(this).unbind("change", up);
            $(this).trigger('focus')
        }

        $(elementId).focus(down).blur(up).focus();
    }
}

        append_textarea('#example', '#select', '.tail');
        $('#select').on('click', function () {
            $('#example').focus();
        });
        $('#click').on('click', function () {
            $('#example').focus();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .tail {
        position: absolute;
    }
    textarea {
        min-width: 250px;
        min-height: 100px;
    }

</style>

<!-- #MAIN PANEL -->
<div id="main" role="main">

    <!-- RIBBON -->
    <div id="ribbon">

        <!-- breadcrumb -->
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li>Home</li>
        </ol>

    </div>

    <!-- col -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-4">
        <h1 class="page-title txt-color-blueDark"></h1>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <textarea  id="example"></textarea>
        <div class="tail" hidden>
            <select id="select">
                <option style="display: none;">Please select one</option>
                <option value="USER_NAME}">First and Last Name</option>
                <option value="WO_NO}">Work Order Number</option>
                <option value="PROD}">Product Name and Size</option>
                <option value="PROJECT}">Project Name</option>
                <option value="MACHINE}">Machine Name</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="button" value="CLICK ME!" id="click">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://rawgit.com/Codecademy/textarea-helper/master/textarea-helper.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried to make your code runnable as a code snippet, but it's probably not working, as I can't see what I need to do in order to reproduce the problem you're seeing.

Comment: If you run code snipped and while writing open curly bracket list with options will open. After choosing one of the options I would like to move caret back to textarea but function focus() is not being called.

Comment: OK, now I see the popup, but after I choose one of the items (either with mouse or by pressing Enter), the textarea is focussed as expected... I'm testing on Firefox.

Comment: Unfortunately my platform is designed to work on Chrome and code doesn't work on it. But thanks for feedback.

Comment: That's something you ought to have mentioned in the question.. Note that removing `.blur(up)` or `$(this).trigger('focus')` in `up` makes the focus work.